# Authentication in development and integration tests

Tags: authentication, integration-testing

What is the best practice for setting authentication in different runtime scenarios (e.g. Production, development, testing and possibly others)

Do you set up a different authentication settings for each one, (e.g. different token issuers per runtime environment) or create a bypass for developers? Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I create a limited rights *guest* account, and have the runner authenticate as that user.

Think of the **Guest** account in Windows:

> **SID:** S-1-5-21-`domain`-501
>   **Name:** Guest
>   **Description:** A user account for people who do not have individual accounts. This user account does not require a password. By default, the Guest account is disabled.

Comment: Is that account just an AAD entity, or something deeper than that?